# How to correct a Load Error of Nokogiri using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, load, nokogiri

I am quite sure I have exhausted every other resource trying to figure out why I keep getting a load error. There is something about nokogiri, bootsnap and spring that keeps coming up .
I am using ruby on rails and when I try to start the server or console to do anything I get this error which I do not understand how to follow. I removed parts of the error message bc it is just too long for a post.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        106: from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
        105: from bin/rails:2:in `load'
        104: ...
 could not use '/Users/allisonperry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/nokogiri-1.11.1-arm64-darwin/lib/nokogiri/2.6/nokogiri.bundle' 
because it is not a compatible arch - /Users/allisonperry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/nokogiri-1.11.1-arm64-darwin/lib/nokogiri/2.6/nokogiri.bundle (LoadError)
```

Gemfile...

```
ruby '2.6.3'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.2', '>= 6.1.2.1'gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'
gem 'bootsnap', require: false
gem 'nokogiri'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

This in on mac OS big sur 11.1.

I have tried SOOOO MUCH and nothing works.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the ruby install on the mac. This is an interesting read...https://github.sre.pub/rubygems/rubygems/issues/4234 -

Comment: @dbugger mac OS big sur 11.1

Comment: @dbugger thank you for the article it is interesting and also good to see that I am not just going crazy. I am way too new to things to understand how to solve things the ways they mention sadly

Comment: @dbugger I am not on an M1 and I honestly don't know for sure re: ruby installation. I might be using what came with the mac. I do know I updated it as one of the things I attempted first. jordan you are correct about the arm64 but I have had both installed, uninstalled, done it one at a time... so when I just installed nokogiri again it said x86_64, then I tried 'rails s' and it said "
Could not find nokogiri-1.11.1-arm64-darwin in any of the sources" and  from there I ran bundle update and it said "Installing nokogiri 1.11.1 (arm64-darwin)"..... like what on earth!

Comment: Install rvm https://rvm.io/ and reinstall Ruby with rvm.

Comment: @dbugger so I had an issue even with installing rvm but that did lead me on the path to eventually correcting all of the issues that didn't align... honestly I have no idea what happened but you and also the other commenter Jordan were very helpful and I cannot thank you enough!

Comment: Happy you were able to get it working -- that is a nasty issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you installed an arm64 version and it is not compatible with your device.

Comment: I would try installing an x86_64 version of nokogiri and see of that works. sorry for double posting but it wouldn't let me edit my original answer